# On the "Deep End" of an angle

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

**Definition of the Deep End:** In hyperbolic geometry, for any angle  $\angle ABC$, there are points $D$ between the rays $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$ such that none of the straights through $D$ can cross both rays $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$. These points are told to be in the "Deep End" of the interior angle of $\angle ABC$.

Assume point $D$ is in the Deep End of  $\angle ABC$ and $E$ is a point on  $\overrightarrow{BD}$ such that $D$ is between $B$ and $E$. Prove $E$ is in the Deep End of  $\angle ABC$.

[image]

My idea is to suppose that $E$ is not in the deep end. So then the ray containing it will cross both $BA$ and $BC$ which would contradict the assumption that $D$ is in the deep end. I don't feel this is fully justified though.

Comment: I don't understand this definition of "deep end". For any interior point $D$, draw the angle with $D$ at the vertex and sides parallel to $\overline {BA}$ and $\overline {BC}$. Any line through $D$ interior to this angle will intersect only one of $\vec{BA},\vec {BC}$. Any line through $D$ external to this angle will intersect both rays. There is no interpretation of that definition that doesn't either apply to all points inside $\angle ABC$ or to none of them. Do you perhaps mean "line segments $BA$ and $BC$" instead of "rays"?

Comment: Nevermind my last suggestion - that change would just make "Deep End" equivalent to "inside $\angle ABC$, but outside $\triangle ABC$"

Comment: I keep forgetting that you're studying non-Euclidean geometry, and I somehow consistently fail to notice the `hyperbolic-geometry` tag, so I repeatedly find myself scratching my head at your questions on first read. :)  As a favor to me, could you occasionally drop the word "hyperbolic" (or "neutral" or whatever's appropriate) into your descriptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT TO INTUIT THE PROBLEM**

The following figure depicts the deep end of the angle $\angle ABC $ in the Beltrami-Klein model.

[image]

Here, $p$ is the common parallel to the rays $BC$ and $BA$. The yellow region is the Deep End; $p$ belongs to it. If $D$ is in the Deep End then $E$ is - a fortiory - in it.

Comment: I was about to post the corresponding image for the Poincaré model. :)

Comment: Why the Poincaré model? (Seriously: why do people prefer the Poncaré model?)

Comment: I guess I just like circles. :) I also like that the Poincaré model is conformal.

Comment: @Blue: Understood, and thank you.